# SQL insert into select bulk insertion duplication not checking on every row

Tags: sql, insert

I need to insert data into table using select query and where condition, the problem is if i have 100 records to be inserted with the condition, all records are inserted in one time and still have duplicated records but in where clause i am checking on fields already exists to prevent the insertion

below the code

```
insert into table1 select CONVERT(date,dt.Date, 103)
     FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',  
'Data Source=\\pc\test\TEST.xls;Extended Properties=EXCEL 5.0')...[Sheet1$] dt
 ,Employee Emp where
     Emp.FileEmployeeID = [EMployee ID] 
     and not exists (select * from EmployeeAttendance empatt  where  //condition to not insert the row already exists
 empatt.Date=Convert(datetime,dt.Date,103)
    and 
      empatt.EmployeeID=Emp.Id and dt.in_ != empatt.TimeIn and dt.out_!=empatt.TimeOut)
```

the excel file contains 2 exact record after insert first one, the second one is inserted normally(the query not checking if the first one already exists)

Comment: So is there is a conflict with the data being inserted? Or the existing data in the table before the insert?

Comment: the conflict exists on the data being inserted, not the existing

Comment: add a unique index to the table instead? What's happening is since it's a bulk insert it's all in one transaction.  Since the not exists is executing against the base table before the records are committed, it's not finding the record your inserting as part of the bulk insert.  Either remove the duplicates before the insert; or possibly use a duplicate key index; or insert into a temp table 1st, then select the unique records from it and only insert those.

Comment: @xQbert i have added index on the 4 fields i am checking on it it return `Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.EmployeeAttendance' with unique index 'EmployeeIdDate'`

Comment: If you had no "Joe Bloggs" in your table1 at the time you tried to import a spreadsheet with two "Joe Bloggs" records then you will get both duplicates.  If you already had a "Joe Bloggs" then neither of the two records would be re-imported.

Comment: I generally load all data into a temp table first.  Then select against that temp table to transform/cleanse the data.  In this case i'd use `Row_number() over (partition by unique fields) RN` and then only select those records with a RN=1 that don't exist in target table.  This way you eliminate duplicates in source, and don't insert those that already exist.  Or you could just use a distinct if all columns are what denote a unique record...  ensuring to check target for no records as well... or you could insert these and records from target table into one table and then select distinct...

Comment: is there a method to let the index insert only one record from duplicated ?